# Can SSH into server but cannot type anything in the prompt. What is a possible cause for that?

Tags: linux, ssh

I can ssh into one of my servers, I log in fine, but at the prompt I cannot type anything. It just hangs there after the welcome message.

I've also tried the DRAC console (its a Dell server), but I get a blank dark screen without any output when I call up a remote console.

I cannot reboot this machine at this time nor am I physically near it. I've tried to log in as all root as well without any luck. The box itself functions ok at the moment but I'm now worried as this is a critical production machine.

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: What happens if you execute command like this: `$ ssh -t -t user@ip "w"`?

Comment: I get the output of w, showing my stuck logins:

 11:13:47 up 128 days, 17:59,  3 users,  load average: 6.44, 6.03, 5.01
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
harel    pts/0    hulk             10:08    1:05m  0.25s  0.25s -bash
root     pts/4    hulk             10:56   17:02   0.11s  0.11s -bash
harel    pts/6    hulk             11:13    0.00s  0.00s  0.00s w

Comment: But its inconsistent. Seems like its down to chance: other commands I run, including a rerun of your "w" fail in the same way.

Comment: Did you try with another user or from different machine?

Comment: Yes. This server has 2 users (me and root) and is not publicly available. I tried from a few different servers with the same outcome. The only thing I can think of right now is rebooting it but I can't do it now and I'm even more worried to the fate of the data on it.

Comment: Are there backups of the machine? Rebooting when in this state, you need to make sure your backup/recovery plan is in place (preferably before now...)

Comment: No. This was due to have another failover machine put in place but its not in yet. Its a mongodb server, running version 2.x with journalled data. I am putting my hopes on the mongo team at this stage.

Comment: I can however get a mongo shell to that machine from another box. I will try to initiate a backup from that.

Comment: Data is backed up. I will have to restart it tonight to find out what went wrong I think.
Thanks for the help

Comment: If you can issue commands like "w" above, you can do other things like "ps waxl" "dmesg" "tail -500 /var/log/syslog" and such.

Comment: can you get the output of a `df`, see if any of the drives are full (particularly wherever you keep logs).

Comment: I tried to issue a df and other commands like 'ps' but its 99% of the time hangs and very rarely returns anything. The only time I did got anything back was my first 'w'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment discussion this sounds like the behavior you see when you are experiencing packet loss due to MTU/fragmentation issues:

http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html

This usually shows up as being able to login to the machine but some commands fail (usually a significant percentage of the time).  You can verify that this isn't the issue by getting the same behavior on a machine connected to the same LAN as the box having the problems.  If that session works fine, then you probably need to start looking at the network layer between you and the machine in question.

Comment: I think you might be right. A reboot of the server resolved the problem. Its the first I've ever seen it, and that server has been online for about 128 days before that hit it. Other servers on same subnet were fine.